# JQuery $.ajax by sending POST receiving 400 Bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, jakarta-ee

Continually receiving 400 (Bad Request) on jquery ajax post to MVC controller. I've tried to send simple data, array, with and without JSON.stringify... and I ran out of ideas. 
What else could it be?

**Ajax send**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../../taskaction/send',
    data: JSON.stringify({idTaskAction: 2, actioname: 3}),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('@Success sending action status: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('@Error sending action status: ' + textStatus);
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/taskaction/send", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> sendAction(Principal principal,
        @RequestBody Map<String, Object> data, @PathVariable Long id) {
    logger.info("Task controller /taskaction/send ...");

  String actionname = (String) data.get("actionname");

  System.out.println("*****>>>>>>" + actionname );

  Map<String, Object> rdata = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  TaskAction action = null;

  rdata.put("success", true);

  return rdata;
}
```

**HTTP Request from inspector**

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/myTasks/taskaction/send
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Petición incorrecta
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:33
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=9073BF5FA653C2C673AD9BCB787732C3
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/myTasks/task/upd/8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{idTaskAction:2, actionname:3}
actionname: 3
idTaskAction: 2
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Language:es
Content-Length:990
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 20 Sep 2014 13:19:31 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's because your handler method is expecting a @PathVariable named id which can be converted into a Long, however in your POST request, you're not sending in that argument and in your @RequestMapping, you haven't defined a URI template variable for id.

Something like the following contains the id as a URI template variable and so long as the value you pass can be converted to a Long, the request should be handled by your request handler method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/taskaction/send/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
```

Only other thing I can't comment on (and might get negative comments for) is using a Map as a @RequestBody.  In my experience, using a concrete object type with fields defined on it has worked better.  I think your real problem though is your @RequestMapping and @PathVariable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking in a completly wrong place! I was checking the json data that I was sending to the server.